# Domain Driven Design (DDD) and database generated reports

Tags: database, domain-driven-design, persistence

I'm still investigating DDD, but I'm curious to know about one potential pitfall.

According to DDD an aggregate-root shouldn't know about persistence, but doesn't that mean the entire aggregate-root ends up being instantiated in memory?

How could the aggregate-root, for instance, ask the database to group and sum a lot of data if it's not supposed to know about persistence?

Comment: To clarify, the use case is a contract that has multiple timesheet entries attached to it, each with a monetary amount.

The total amount of money spent on the contract is calculated by summing the amounts of the timesheet entries.

Comment: How many timesheet entries would there typically be per contract? Are there business rules to enforce when adding entries?

Comment: It could vary from 60 up to 750 entries. There are business rules to enforce, such as checking the chosen Rate is valid for the Contract and time/date.

Comment: Do the business rules require all entries to be loaded?

Comment: No, the business rules are applied during creation and editing of an entry, so they could be considered individually against a Contract.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need to load them all in your aggregate. You can have a read model for displaying items that shows them all and only load a single one when necessary in your write / command side - just split the read and write side = CQRS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to DDD an aggregate-root shouldn't know about persistence, but doesn't that mean the entire aggregate-root ends up being instantiated in memory?

Oh no, it's worse than that; the entire *aggregate* (the root and all of the subordinate entities) get loaded instantiated in memory.   Essentially by definition, you need all of the state loaded in order to validate any change.

> How could the aggregate-root, for instance, ask the database to group and sum a lot of data if it's not supposed to know about persistence?

You don't need the aggregate-root to do that.

The primary role of the domain model is to ensure the integrity of the book of record by ensuring that all writes respect your business invariant.  A read, like a database report, isn't going to change the book of record, so you don't need to load the domain model.

If the domain model itself needs the report, it typically defines a service provider interface that specifies the report that it needs, and your persistence component is responsible for figuring out how to implement that interface.

Answer (score 2):

> According to DDD an aggregate-root shouldn't know about persistence, but doesn't that mean the entire aggregate-root ends up being instantiated in memory?

Aggregate roots are consistency boundaries, so yes you would typically load the whole aggregate into memory in order to enforce invariants. If this sounds like a problem it is probably a hint that your aggregate is too big and possibly in need of refactoring.

> How could the aggregate-root, for instance, ask the database to group and sum a lot of data if it's not supposed to know about persistence?

The aggregate wouldn't ask the database to group and sum data - typically you would load the aggregate in an application service / command handler. For example:

```
public class SomeUseCaseHandler : IHandle<SomeCommand>
{
    private readonly ISomeRepository _someRepository;
    public SomeUseCaseHandler(ISomeRepository someRepository)
    {
        _someRepository = someRepository;
    }

    public void When(SomeCommand command)
    {
        var someAggregaate = _someRepository.Load(command.AggregateId);
        someAggregate.DoSomething();
        _someRepository.Save(someAggregate);
    }
}
```

So your aggregate remains ignore of how it is persisted. However, your implementation of ISomeRepository is *not* ignorant, so can do whatever is necessary to fully load the aggregate. So you *could* have your persistence implementation group/sum when loading the aggregate, but more often you would probably query a read model:

```
public class SomeUseCaseHandler : IHandle<SomeCommand>
{
    private readonly ISomeRepository _someRepository;
    private readonly ISomeReadModel _someReadModel;

    public SomeUseCaseHandler(ISomeRepository someRepository, ISomeReadModel readModel)
    {
        _someRepository = someRepository;
        _someReadModel = someReadModel;
    }

    public void When(SomeCommand command)
    {
        var someAggregaate = _someRepository.Load(command.AggregateId);
        someAggregate.DoSomethingThatRequiresTheReadModel(_someReadModel);
        _someRepository.Save(someAggregate);
    }
}
```

You haven't actually said what your use case is though. :)

[Update]

Just noticed the title refers to database generated reports - this will not go through your domain model at all, it would be a completely separate read model. CQRS applies here